# How get and output description of VarDecl in clang?

Tags: output, clang, oclint

I'm writing OCLint rule based on `VisitBlockDecl` using clang.
How can I output to console value of `VarDecl *var` variable?

```
static SmallVector<VarDecl *, 4> blockVars;

for (int i=0; i < blockVars.size(); i++) {
   VarDecl *var = blockVars[i];
}
```